# C, How to Remove Element From Queue?

Tags: c, list, algorithm, data-structures, queue

**Update:** we believe to find some bugs in both solutions , you are invited to share your ideas too :)

I was trying to implement my own data structure which combines list with queue in C.

my data structure has 2 pointers, front which points to the oldest member in the queue and rear which points to the newly added member which each member points to the one **which got inserted after it**.

For example if I insert 1 then 2 then 3, I will have:

```
NULL <-3 <- 2 <- 1 // 1 is front and 3 is rear.
```

Now I wanted to support removing element from this DS so I starting imeplemnting it and descovvered tens of edge cases like:

1. if the member is the front then change the front for DS and free the member, BUT if the front is null now then change rear to null too or the other code won't work as expected.
2. if the member is in middle release it then go back to prev member and update its next But this seems really hard
3. nearly the same for the rear member except we need to update rear now and only change the pointer to the element to its right (NULL is to its left)

How am I supposed to do something like this?

I already had tens of ideas and implementation for days but simply all failed or I did something really bad making the run time complexity much higher or I wrote 170 lines which had contradictions and left unfinished conditions (by using 2 pointers).

Any help please implementing this?

```
struct queue_node
{
    int key;
    struct queue_node *next;
};

struct queue
{
    int queue_size;
    struct queue_node *front, *rear;
};

int requeue(struct queue *q, int val)
{
    struct queue_node *tmp = q->front;
    while (tmp!=NULL)
    {
        if (tmp->key==val)
        {
            if (tmp==q->front)
            {
                q->front=tmp->next;
                if (q->front == NULL)
                {
                    q->rear = NULL;
                }
                free(tmp);
            }else if (tmp == q->rear)
            {

            }
            return 0; // found
        }
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct queue_node
{
    int key;
    struct queue_node *next;
}node;

typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    node *head;
    node *tail;
}queue;

node *append(queue *q, int key)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    node *c = q -> head;
    if(n)
    {
        if(!q -> head) q -> head = n;
        else
        {
            while(c -> next) c = c -> next;
            c -> next = n;
        }
        n -> key = key;
        n -> next = NULL;
        q -> size++;
        q -> tail = n;
    }
    return n;
}

int removenode(queue *q, int key)
{
    node *n = q -> head, *p = q -> head;
    int result = 0;
    while(n)
    {
        if(n -> key == key)
        {
            if(n == p)
            {
                q -> head = n -> next;
                if(!n -> next) q -> tail = n;
            }
            else
            {
                p -> next = n -> next;                
                if(!p -> next) q -> tail = p;
            } 
            free(n);
            q -> size--;
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
        if(p != n) p = p -> next;
        n = n -> next;
    }
    return result;
}

void printqueue(queue *q)
{
    node *n = q -> head;
    printf("The queue:\n");
    while(n)
    {
        printf("Node key = %d\n", n -> key);
        n = n -> next;
    }
    printf("--------------\n");
    if(q -> head) printf("Head key: %d, Tail key: %d, Queue size: %zu\n -------------\n\n", q -> head -> key, q -> tail -> key, q -> size);
    else printf("Queue empty\n------------\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    queue q = {0,};
    append(&q,1);
    append(&q,2);
    append(&q,3);
    append(&q,4);
    printqueue(&q);
    removenode(&q,3);
    printqueue(&q);
    removenode(&q,1);
    printqueue(&q);
    removenode(&q,4);
    printqueue(&q);
    removenode(&q,2);
    printqueue(&q);

}
```

Result:

```
The queue:
Node key = 1
Node key = 2
Node key = 3
Node key = 4
--------------
Head key: 1, Tail key: 4, Queue size: 4
 -------------

The queue:
Node key = 1
Node key = 2
Node key = 4
--------------
Head key: 1, Tail key: 4, Queue size: 3
 -------------

The queue:
Node key = 2
Node key = 4
--------------
Head key: 2, Tail key: 4, Queue size: 2
 -------------

The queue:
Node key = 2
--------------
Head key: 2, Tail key: 2, Queue size: 1
 -------------

The queue:
--------------
Queue empty
------------
```

[Program demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVAB9LclIj2yAnjqVMtdAGFUrAK4BbWiG4BWUqfQAZPLUwA5OwCNMYhAAdhDSAAdUIUIjWksbe0cXKJjDOk9vP1tA4LDdTH102gYCZmICBLsHZwKiuNLygkzfAKDQ8KEyiqqk2q6mluzcjoBKXVRrYmQOKQBSACYAZi9kGywAajml8y78VAA6BG3sOZkAQUWV2jXrTe3dgnRWPH8jk7PLi4IATwjMLBUDZdYjWAwbACO1kw0I0tAwmE%2BcxCACFPhsMRsvAQNgBrTA/bZoi6Y4EEUHgqEwzBwhEbABU3nEBCJSJCABF4VhWRdPr9/oCyRScWziedSTEAF40nFSxFLMWkrmYBkITDMdA88WY5UMsp4Vha5HsqnQo0XXX05gRf5mCCmlX0iGkLH0PEE0ai9E6umMrZLdkbWxsVioZAQOWoKgQRmjT0K70Yy3If2BiEbAC0Jw2ao1WtJeGjtE9JMxyMVpMxhYgYDA6azS2wOfV6FGkMz2dz6FTG1o%2BcrGMKIkTlfLI4HGIA7ggDZgICmG02mQQ2yntoGF9nl/2J5jN43e5hmT2%2BwnSwPjeOdR2D/ifj27zvK7Qb0ujyKAxsfAJ3O4n6T62zOVFjRBY0TPbUB0Ag99VYE8n0vc8NmITACCmF9TzFRCvnObFkMwWxUAAN1MBF7WhaEGWdV0cTvEtLlREdLRfdd20XZsNRdekIh7aCmy7J88JQoRrFYD9AxkJ9p1nCBixHMckILItX3de911YuirwxBTIN3LFlPUz8InovSy0YxTTLYzsWxPFTtwgyzK2rWsX3Y5c2z4jZYPghzLOwxyh0RCyL3M3THJ4tz31syLmSJRzSS0vTnLACKt3fDyVO81iIn/CdjS2YLKyoFC5zk3zTM8uUMwbCtTOE0TxI2ThcoHfwUOYXEWq2DlEurHja1Y4sNh47K7PfLqWM/Vy0ti8ruvZEcULQ4gX3qsSjR63kLiI1A8G7CJiGxB1yOpKj6J0pVfUmtMVIEuaDuxaNFgWAAVNVIQojg5iccw%2BwWBZ41qjZpPYWSTLMoHSQe%2Bgnv%2Bnw6TvHtFicTUfr%2BhYXWm28PQm6KZpZOb/MxaGCFhhZqopymqe%2B37nsBkdq08rs2xJsmAAkbLvEAtgWFGXRe5gDVU7nkfQF0AEVPuBPBpRF3nJWsGnXKplWszRpXnpdJmbPYu8tcywW4N1gl9fYuV6aQwLhsOmGIGeyXToIiJfiV1XqfV9X/othiFq23C3WDLwIB2vbztCgCpfTVjyxkUhLzm61bXQO2FgANmdThvdJRO3BT9PSABp8c7tRZ86WLPMWL5PS%2BdbgK4xEnjpr%2Bv8MIkjlTz51y6fRvPs7luULb0isE70hM57m2CCbtOIQHgjiOHuca9IOuJ6Ovvm6fQeF475fC/uyfp/T722XZKRxlYaQnHkBxZHkVBpHMYFJmmFUrk4eQCGkOQ41IXEQCWKnA4zgAAcSxwEQMgYAlQ0huDyFsFwGQsdb5yFIA/KQ8ghAgFjl/O%2B4w4CwCQGgWwERZxkAoPOVAJCyEoGAJwehfADQECCFgiA/hv7yH8F4coPxpAf1IMQ2wpgCAAHlaCsF4XfUgWBgzqHYBw6ReAUIGDwCRLBUijyYGQNYZhfD5DYkKAol4bUeGWCwAo8keAEFSA/uMfgjAWDyJ4HwOgBBhBiEkFIpQGNVDqBAFoDQOhjFYMgOMVAzs4jqIzCImQmYADqIZ4nvmIMwTMVAQR4AMBmBexAqChknJgwoWjigmDML0BwnBXBmCGG0YIlTUixDoOU5QDTig1JyO0SpehikNG6JUKw1RlDdJUXQRoFR2kjC6X05pUzBheFaB0up4whAvxmFwC%2BV8b4KPQeIEBqcMyp24BsYAyAUz0IOJwDYEBcCEBIDzJYlSNiWGoewYg9yAZPM/hw3%2BXZ2gQHGP/B5BwwgyDAVAyBqcYFSDgaQBBnAkGkBQffaQmDsGkFwT/UgBDEAgE0doog5DKDlGAEIUQahCgMAQKgSct9%2BHENIaoYoZLvCsEpdSpFAiqEMvaMgOhDD6VkJETotlNKFF4vOMQElKLXDiC0aUfAt95D2KYGwDgzj7HuIkAopQlTfGaG0CoV4IT/loIiXQdRmDVlqt0E8LwzKKVUtFTY%2BQk4UkRD0RsqQ19EXbOkLs/ZhzjmnKapwC5GxsCyvxXc65%2BACX3Mzp89F3zxi/OCCawFoaQVgvBeAyFl9oVbKkeg1FODk1QoWIW1Bxak14PGCRYgMRjDcCAA)

Comment: Hi, I will take a look at your code, can you kindly describe what changed a few sec ago

Comment: found a bug too, it really sounds this problem is too hard :) what if it's empty? you are returning 0

Comment: `0` means no success. Success is `1` It is quite clear in the code. Ir returns **`1`** on success. No bug. Different convention

Comment: by head you mean front or rear (I guess front)

Comment: head is always at front. It is common naming convention:  head and tail. Rear can be understood very different way :) Avoid :)

Comment: got you accepting yours, can you kindly join the conversation with vlad, he is so stubborn :) valgrind says there is a bug and he doesn't agree.

Comment: TBH I didn't expect that reaction I mean it's clear I showed him the output too. that's sad I am not feeling good :|

Answer (score 1):

The function can be defined the following way

```
int requeue( struct queue *q, int val )
{
    struct queue_node **current = &q->front;
    struct queue_node *prev = NULL;

    while ( *current && ( *current )->key != val )
    { 
        prev = *current;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    int success = *current == NULL ? -1 : 0;

    if ( success == 0 )
    {
        struct queue_node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        free( tmp );
        --q->queue_size;            

        if ( *current == NULL ) q->rear = prev;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queue_node
{
    int key;
    struct queue_node *next;
};

struct queue
{
    int queue_size;
    struct queue_node *front, *rear;
};

int requeue( struct queue *q, int val )
{
    struct queue_node **current = &q->front;
    struct queue_node *prev = NULL;

    while ( *current && ( *current )->key != val )
    { 
        prev = *current;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    int success = *current == NULL ? -1 : 0;

    if ( success == 0 )
    {
        struct queue_node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        free( tmp );
        --q->queue_size;            

        if ( *current == NULL ) q->rear = prev;
    }

    return success;
}


int push( struct queue *q, int key )
{
    struct queue_node *node = malloc( sizeof( struct queue_node ) );
    int success = node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        node->key = key;
        node->next = NULL;
        
        if ( q->rear == NULL )
        {
            q->front = q->rear = node;
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear = q->rear->next = node;
        }

        ++q->queue_size;            
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( const struct queue *q )
{
    for ( struct queue_node *current = q->front; current; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->key );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct queue q = { .front = NULL, .rear = NULL };
    
    push( &q, 1 );
    push( &q, 2 );
    push( &q, 3 );
    push( &q, 4 );
    
    display( &q );
    
    requeue( &q, 4 );

    display( &q );

    push( &q, 4 );

    display( &q );

    requeue( &q, 1 );

    display( &q );

    requeue( &q, 3 );

    display( &q );

    requeue( &q, 4 );

    display( &q );

    requeue( &q, 2 );

    display( &q );

    push( &q, 1 );
    push( &q, 2 );
    push( &q, 3 );
    push( &q, 4 );
    
    display( &q );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
2 -> 4 -> null
2 -> null
null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
```

If for testing to add a call of the function `printf` to this code snippet within the function `requeue`

```
if ( success == 0 )
{
    struct queue_node *tmp = *current;
    *current = ( *current )->next;
    printf( "tmp->key == %d, tmp == %p\n", tmp->key, ( void * )tmp );
    free( tmp );
    --q->queue_size;            

    if ( *current == NULL ) q->rear = prev;
}
```

Then the output of the demonstrative program can look like

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
tmp->key == 4, tmp == 0x55b55f9e02c0
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
tmp->key == 1, tmp == 0x55b55f9e0260
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
tmp->key == 3, tmp == 0x55b55f9e02a0
2 -> 4 -> null
tmp->key == 4, tmp == 0x55b55f9e02c0
2 -> null
tmp->key == 2, tmp == 0x55b55f9e0280
null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
```

Comment: thanks but it has some bugs, for example rear isn't being updated in your code

Comment: @lord97 This statement if ( *current == NULL ) q->rear = prev; updates rear.

Comment: @lord97 The function has neither bug.

Comment: @lord97 See my demonstrative program The pointer front is updated.:)

Comment: This is a bug: "&( *current )->next" it could be NULL and you are dereferencing it

Comment: @lord97 One more there is no bugs. Do not invent bugs.:) Just run the demonstrative program.

Comment: @0___________ It compiles. I forgot about the data member queue_size and now I added its updating to the functions.

Comment: Imagine there is one single node 7 and we are looking for 5, then we enter the while loop, prev points to node 7 and current goes to &NULL which is illegal. why? because ( *current )->next is null in this case... @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @0___________ do you agree with me? that's a bug

Comment: @lord97 As I said do not invent bugs. Neither null pointer is dereferenced in the function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ??? I do not understand the question

Comment: @VladfromMoscow in the case of 7. Does it remove something?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow then what's wrong about what I said?

Comment: @lord97 The condition of the loop is while ( *current && ( *current )->key != val ) So within the loop *current can not be equal to NULL. current is declared as a pointer to pointer struct queue_node **current = &q->front;

Comment: @0___________ There is neither undefined behavior. Do not invent any undefined behavior.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow your code is equal to: `    while ( *current && ( *current )->key != val )
    {
        prev = *current;
        struct queue_node * tmp=( *current )->next;
        current = &tmp;
    }`   and tmp here is NULL

Comment: @0___________ One more neither null pointer is dereferenced. There is written very clear     int success = *current == NULL ? -1 : 0;

    if ( success == 0 ) And within the while loop *current can not be a null pointer due to the condition while ( *current && ( *current )->key != val )

Comment: vlad go to chat I will show you I am 100% sure, we are talking inside the while loop

Comment: @lord97 I am sorry but the problem is that you do not understand the code. There is neither bug in the function.

Comment: (*current) can't be null but ( *current )->next; can be and you are deferencing it @0___________ agreess with me too

Comment: @lord97 If *current is not equal to NULL then in this expression ( *current )->next current still is not equal to NULL.:)

Comment: are you sure? take a look https://ibb.co/cbgKh3Z @VladfromMoscow

Comment: this is undefined bahaviour

Comment: @lord97 I am sure. Nowhere in the function a null pointer is dereferenced. Show me the statement where it is dereferenced.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just sent you the image from Clion it clearly says tmp is NULL. even ran valgrind too and it agrees

Comment: @lord97 This code snippet     if ( success == 0 )
    {
        struct queue_node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        free( tmp );
        --q->queue_size;;            

        if ( *current == NULL ) q->rear = prev;
    } gets the control when *current is not equal to NULL due to the preceding declaration int success = *current == NULL ? -1 : 0; that is when success is equal to 0 that means that *current is not equal to NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this is your code take a look, put a breakpoint at line 25 `current = &tmp;`. tmp is NULL which is a bug. again I ran valgrind too and it agrees and here is another clear proof

Comment: @lord97 What you need is to understand how the function works.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how is that related? I showed you clearly that at line 25 tmp is NULL and you are trying to deference it. it's not me it's the debugger that's your code why you refuse to take a look at the value of tmp?

Comment: @lord97 Just add a statement with a call of printf like       struct queue_node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        printf( "tmp->key == %d, tmp == %p\n", tmp->key, ( void * )tmp );
        free( tmp );
  inside the function and see the output of the demonstrative program.

Comment: @lord97 It means that you understand neither the function definition nor valgrind.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow for god's sake valgrind says it clear deference of NULL ptr! what isn't clear about this. you refuse to run valgrind and refuse to see the debugger output.

Comment: @lord97 See my appended answer specially for you. As it is seen the pointer tmp is never equal to NULL. It just can not be equal to NULL.:) Investigate the function definition.

Comment: then why clion says clearly it's null? how can you explain this? @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @lord97 It means that you are looking in a non right place.:) For me it is not interesting because it is another question. I answered your original question providing the function definition. It took 5 minutes for me. But answering your comments took much more time about an hour.:)

Comment: what do you mean? "It means that you are looking in a non right place.:)" this line is part of your code and one line after it you are deferencing NULL ptr what isn't clear about this? sorry but your solution is wrong

Comment: @lord97 I already pointed out that within this code snippet     int success = *current == NULL ? -1 : 0;

    if ( success == 0 )
    {
        struct queue_node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        free( tmp );
        --q->queue_size;;            

        if ( *current == NULL ) q->rear = prev;
    } the pointer *current and the pointer tmp can not be equal to NULL.  How it can be equal to NULL if success is equal to 0?! Where is a null pointer dereferenced?! And moreover the program output shows that neither pointer is ever equal to NULL.

Comment: @lord97 By the way you can ask a question at SO about your opinion that there is dereferenced a null pointer in the function.:)